# Set TinyMCE text editor to readonly in code behind

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How can you make the tinyMCE text editor readonly in code behind on an aspnet webforms page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a configuration option (`readonly: true`) for TinyMCE to make it readonly:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: [
      "advlist autolink...."
  ],
  readonly: true,
  toolbar: "insertfile undo redo...."
});
```

There is also a setMode API that you can use at runtime to change the editor instance to readonly:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setmode

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows both of these in action:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Glgaab

Comment: Thanks, my issue is I need to toggle it from enabled/writeable to readonly/non-editable after a button click based on logic in a postback in my C# codebehind. I am able to hide it using the following code -RichTextBox.Style.Add("display", "none"); but would prefer to disable it.

Comment: I don't know much about C# but doesn't a code behind file run on a server?  TinyMCE runs 100% client side so you can't execute TinyMCE API calls or interact with the editor via server-side code - if there is a way to send JS back to the browser perhaps you could do that.

Comment: That is correct it runs on the server however you can do some things that send the settings back to the client to make things readonly, hidden, etc...